# Accessing JSP variables from JSF EL

Tags: jsp, jsf, el

I'm trying to do something like (in a JSP page, running with JavaServer Faces):

```
<%
String myTitle = "Cool Action!";
String myAction = "coolAction";
%>

<h:commandLink value="#{myTitle}" action="#{myAction}" />
```

This isn't working, because JSF can't see the JSP variables (at least with this notation?).

Is there a way to access JSP variables from JSF tags (without using a session/page-scoped bean), OR is there a way to define JSF tags like commandLink from inside a <% %> JSP block?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put them in at least the request scope. EL resolves among others the attributes of `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpSession` and `ServletContext`.

```
<%
request.setAttribute("myTitle", "Cool Action!");
request.setAttribute("myAction", "coolAction");
%>
```

But this is totally the wrong way of using JSF. To follow the proper MVC design ideology, you should **not** use old fashioned JSP *scriptlets* in any way. Even more, JSP's successor Facelets does not support any form of *scriptlets*.

Depending on the concrete functional requirement, you could create a backing bean class wherein you specify them as bean properties,

```
<h:commandLink value="#{bean.myTitle}" action="#{bean.myAction}" />
```

or just "hardcode" it directly in the `<h:commandLink>`.

```
<h:commandLink value="Cool Action!" action="coolAction" />
```

or put at least the value in an i18n resource bundle which you load by `<f:loadBundle>` or register by `<resource-bundle>` in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<h:commandLink value="#{text['myTitle']}" action="coolAction" />
```